# CSS media query on Full HD (1920px) is acting like other one

Tags: css, responsive-design, sass, media-queries, resolution

Consider the following code:

```
header {
    height: 60px;
    background: red;

    @media (max-width: 1650px) {
        background: blue;
    }
}
```

I work with laptop connected to Full HD (1920 x 1080) Resolution screen/monitor
When i look at the webpage with my screen connected the header has a **red** background, so it doesn't response to the 1650px media query.

When i disconnect my laptop (let's say after i restart it to reset the screen settings) and I open the webpage i find out the header's background is **blue** now - means it responses to the 1650px media query

My question is - my laptop is on 1920 resolution (not connected to screen) but responses to the 1650px media query, why is this happening? I suppose to see the webpage just like when my laptop is connected to the screen, it's the same resolution.

Thanks

Comment: double check the resolution of your screen and your display settings.

Answer (score 0):

Because in your system is the scale of the interface for the laptop screen, which programmatically makes it somewhere in the width of 1400 pixels, but the picture continues to be rendered in 1920.

Answer (score -2):

Your Media Query can't ne inside the styling for `.header`, the brackets have not been closed correctly.

**Use this:**

```
header {
    height: 60px;
    background: red;
}

@media (max-width: 1650px) {
    header {
        background: blue;
    }
}
```

Comment: The OP is using SASS, which allows for nested selectors and media queries.